# How to detect black shaped contour on photo with OpenCV-Python

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I am trying to detect black shape on photo like this.

[image]

So far i have picture with shape but still on there is many lines and noise and from that i cannot use the  findContours()  because it's also mark the line. Can You give me some advice or help with this task. I will be so grateful for help!

Original image

[image]

Binary image

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import imutils

def color_seg(choice):
    if choice == 'blue':
        lower_hue = np.array([100,30,30])
        upper_hue = np.array([150,148,255])
    elif choice == 'white':
        lower_hue = np.array([0,0,0])
        upper_hue = np.array([0,0,255])
    elif choice == 'black':
        lower_hue = np.array([0,0,0])
        upper_hue = np.array([50,50,100])
    return lower_hue, upper_hue


# Take each frame
frame = cv2.imread('11.jpg')
#frame = cv2.imread('images/road_1.jpg')

frame = imutils.resize(frame, height = 500)
chosen_color = 'black'


# Convert BGR to HSV
hsv = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

# define range of a color in HSV
lower_hue, upper_hue = color_seg(chosen_color)


# Threshold the HSV image to get only blue colors
mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower_hue, upper_hue)


kernel = np.ones((5,5),np.uint8)
erosion = cv2.erode(mask,kernel,iterations = 10)
erosion = cv2.filter2D(mask,-1,kernel)
erosion = cv2.GaussianBlur(mask,(5,5),cv2.BORDER_DEFAULT)




cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
cv2.imshow('mask',mask)

cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Comment: Suggestion: find the contours. Then either measure the circularity (https://www.programcreek.com/python/example/89409/cv2.fitEllipse) or the eccentricity (https://python.hotexamples.com/examples/cv2/-/fitEllipse/python-fitellipse-function-examples.html) and filter on ones that are more circular (circularity or eccentricity close to 1) and have an area in a reasonable range

Answer (score 3):

You're on the right track. After obtaining your binary image you need to perform [morphological operations](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_morphological_ops/py_morphological_ops.html) to filter out noise and isolate the object. Afterwards, we can find contours then filter using contour approximation and contour area. We draw the detected region onto a blank mask then bitwise-and with the original image. Here's the steps:

Binary image

[image]

Morphological operations

[image]

Detected region in green

[image]

Isolated result after bitwise operations

[image]

Code

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

# Color threshold
image = cv2.imread('1.jpg')
original = image.copy()
blank = np.zeros(image.shape, dtype=np.uint8)
blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(image, (7,7), 0)
hsv = cv2.cvtColor(blur, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
lower = np.array([0, 0, 0])
upper = np.array([179, 93, 97])
mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower, upper)

# Morph operations
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (7,7))
opening = cv2.morphologyEx(mask, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel, iterations=1)
close = cv2.morphologyEx(opening, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel, iterations=2)

# Find contours and filter using contour approximation + contour area
cnts = cv2.findContours(mask, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]
for c in cnts:
    peri = cv2.arcLength(c, True)
    approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(c, 0.04 * peri, True)
    area = cv2.contourArea(c)
    if len(approx) > 3 and area > 1000:
        cv2.drawContours(image, [c], -1, (36,255,12), -1)
        cv2.drawContours(blank, [c], -1, (255,255,255), -1)

# Bitwise-and for result
blank = cv2.cvtColor(blank, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
result = cv2.bitwise_and(original,original,mask=blank)
result[blank==0] = (255,255,255)

cv2.imshow('mask', mask)
cv2.imshow('opening', opening)
cv2.imshow('close', close)
cv2.imshow('result', result)
cv2.imshow('image', image)
cv2.waitKey()
```